# Snowflake stored procedure parallelism

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have snowflake stored procedure written using Javascript. From my main sp1 I'm reading the table names list. Using iterator passing the table name to the sp2 for the data load process.

```
create procedure sp1()
language javascript
$$
  tbllist=['tb1','tbl2','tbl3'];
  for tbl in tbllist:
    stmt='call sp2('tbl')'
$$
```

But the sp2 is getting invoked sequentially. I'm trying to invoke this stored procedure in parallel to process the data.

Is there any solution to achieve this? I tried creating stored procedure using Python language by leveraging snowpark. But it is not invoking queries concurrently.

Comment: Please provide more detail on what's the exact requirement. Also, kindly format your question and code properly so that it's clear. Also, share what you have tried till now so that we know you have done your research before asking this question. What I understand is that you want to run your second stored procedure parallelly and you are looking to leverage Pyspark for the same - correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way of calling one SP from another asynchronously. The first SP will always wait until the second SP completes

Answer (score 0):

Right now there's no way to achieve parallelism from within a Snowflake stored procedure.

An alternative is to use an outside scheduler that sends requests to Snowflake, then it will be the scheduler's job (like Airflow) to send requests in parallel to Snowflake from the outside:

- https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/astronomer-providers/versions/latest/modules/snowflakeoperatorasync

This leverages the Snowflake libraries that can ask for async execution:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-example#label-python-connector-querying-data-asynchronous
- https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.AsyncJob

So while Snowflake can execute many queries/stored procedures in parallel, the orchestration needs to happen from outside a stored procedure.